# animating path in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

following code creates a red 270 degree ring

```
let result = Measurement(value: 270, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
        .converted(to: .radians).value


let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 200,y: 200), radius: CGFloat(90), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(result), clockwise: true)


let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 30.0

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

How would i go about and animate the path being drawn using swift 3

thanks

Comment: You don't say what sort of animation you want. Do you want to animate a change in color? Moving the ring around? Animate drawing the arc of the ring from 0 degrees to 270 degrees?

Comment: animating drawing of the arc

Comment: Take a look at Andy Donzelli's answer then. He explains what to do.

Comment: And for the future, before you post a question, step back from your question and review it from the perspective of a stranger. Have you provided a clear description of what you're trying to do, and of the specific problem you're having in accomplishing that goal? If you're getting an error, did you provide the complete text of the error as well as the line on which it occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAShapeLayer has properties *strokeStart* and *strokeEnd* that define what part of the path you want to draw. Their default values are 0.0 and 1.0 respectively, since you usually want to draw the entire path.

You can *animate* the change of these values using a CABasicAnimation by specifying the "strokeEnd" or "strokeStart" value key, like this:

```
let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
pathAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
pathAnimation.toValue = 1.0
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0   // time in seconds.
shapeLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
```